# How to auto populate values of one object to other objects in salesforce without coding

Tags: trigger, process-builder, customization

is there any way to populate values from one object to other object without writing code.
Please let me know.

Thanks,

Comment: Can you elaborate your requirement? Formulas, Workflows and Process Builder are usual methods for this. Which one to use It depends on your requirement.

Answer (score 2):

This depends on the data model and relationships between those two objects.

In the simplest case you may be able to use a Formula field if the relationships are appropriate.

Your other option would be to use Process Builder and/or Visual Flow.